# How to Pass a XML File to a XMLReader

Tags: java, android, xmlreader

Previously in my Android project I passed a URL String (Web Address) to the `XMLReader` to parse. But now I want to pass the XML File from my the project itself for this purpose.

1. Where should I place the XML File (Note:- After installing it on a device, I expect to **update** the contents of the XML File **weekly**. **Placement of the XML File should be flexible for  this**)
2. How can I retrieve data from the XML File to the `XMLReader`

Previous (Working)

```
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        URL sourceUrl;

        sourceUrl = new URL(
        "http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");


        XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your second question, you can construct an `InputSource` from a `FileInputStream`, similar to what you are doing with the url. I suggest to also set the systemId to get nicer error reporting and in case you need to resolve relative paths from the xml.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(in);
    is.setSystemId(file.getAbsolutePath());
    xr.parse(is);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: It's working with normal java application, but not with the android app

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your first question, you can store the file directly onto the Android phone. Some nice tutorials for that at [Hello Android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/data-storage-tutorial-basic-samples-are-included) and [Skill Guru](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/17/data-storage-mechanisms-in-android/). To illustrate some of the code below:

```
String aFileName = "mydata.xml";

// An output stream
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(aFileName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//An input stream
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
```

For your second question, as has already been suggested, you just create an input source from the file input stream you got in step 1, and your good to go.